# TFS 2015 - SQL Server 2016 licence

Tags: tfs-2015, sql-server-2016

Although SQL Server 2016 is now supported with TFS 2015 Update 3, at present, the TFS Server licence only includes a licence for SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition.

So, Microsoft folk... when will a licence for SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition be subsumed in the TFS 2015 Server licence, and when will the Visual Studio licensing whitepaper be updated to reflect this?

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is a site for programming and developing. (***A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.***)

Your question is more related to the products. I have noticed you have asked the same question and got very detailed response from *Brian Harry MS* in [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/06/07/team-foundation-server-2015-update-3-rc-is-available/). Next time, if you want to get more detailed and up-to-date information about the product TFS and VSO. You can follow [Brian's Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/) and [the news for VSO](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/2016-jul-29-vso).

Moreover, for this question according to the response from *Brian*:

> No, it won’t. The solution is to either purchase a newer version TFS
>   that includes the SQL Server you want or to separately license SQL
>   Server and manage updates independently (like by purchasing SQL Server
>   Software Assurance).